# Dynamic Container Height (jQuery Only)

Tags: jquery, element

I have a fixed-height (180px) header and fixed-height footer (50px). I'd like the container height to be: window height MINUS header MINUS footer. If the container height can be updated on window resize, that'd be awesome!

I posted the same question and receive a great answer with a CSS only solution, it works but still have issues in IE6 and 7, so **I'd like a jquery Only solution if possible**.

Comment: Can you post a link to the previous question you asked? I'm interested in reading the answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900540/dynamic-container-height-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [resize event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/resize), like this: (untested)

```
var expandingDiv = $('...');
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    expandingDiv.height(document.documentElement.clientHeight - (180 + 50));
});
```

Comment: Or use $(window).height() - seems to be more consistent than document.offsetHeight across different browsers and versions.